# Compare JSON with Dictionary and put Key-Value in JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have one dictionary and one one json file. I want to check the data exist in dictionary and put the value pair in the json on the compared attribute.

```
#import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Iris2.csv" , encoding='ISO-8859-1')
df.head()

dict_from_csv = pd.read_csv('Iris2.csv',encoding='ISO-8859-1', header=None, index_col=0, squeeze=True).to_dict()
print(dict_from_csv)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxTDU.png)

And then I read the JSON attribute

```
import pandas as pd
json = pd.read_json (r'C:/Users/IT City/Downloads/data.json')
print(json)
json = pd.read_json (r'C:/Users/IT City/Downloads/data.json')
df.venue_info = pd.DataFrame(json.venue_info.values.tolist())['venue_name']
print(df.venue_info)
```

[enter image description here][2]

Now I have dictionary contains the csv file "dict_from_csv" and json attribute "df.venue_info"

I firstly compared the json venue_name with Dictionary and got the required results. I have the "Lat" attribute finally. And now I want to add this new attribute to JSON file where the "Lat" would be match otherwise it should place empty attribute on that.

```
for x in df.venue_info:
    if((x in dict_from_csv) == True):
        #print(x)
        #print(dict_from_csv[x])
        Lat = x+":"+dict_from_csv[x]
        print(Lat)
    else:
        print("Not found ")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxTDU.png)

Please help me in this regard

Thank you

Comment: `I firstly have to compare if the df.venue_info exist in dictionary then it should get the Value of this key and put or add the new attribute in json for given df.venue_info.`. You have answered your own question. What problem are u facing when doing this ?

Comment: Actually I am new to python so have problem how to add the values in json if it would be in the dictionary

Comment: Look at the `keys()` method that can be used with a dict

Comment: Hi leoOrion I compared the results with dictionary and now have one attribute "Lat" and want to put in the place where venue_name == df.venue_info